# Are questions about consumer electronics such as this on topic here?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about surge protectors on *diy.stackexchange.com* ([Link to the question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/121445/surge-protector-for-appliances-per-appliance-non-standard)) and did not receive an answer. I assume the reason is the lack of sufficient expertise on that site. So I was thinking of asking it here.

Would it be on topic here since it relates to electronics, or would it be off topic because it's not technical enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting that question to DIY.SE was the right decision on your part.  If you posted it to EE.SE, it would get migrated to DIY.SE.  The EE.SE members are good with principles and design, but an electrician would be better with knowledge of the building codes.

Other than that, you can post a link to your DIY.SE question into our [EE.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).

Comment: Thanks. (Can't accept yet.)